# Why does this addition result in NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to add prices to find the total, but `console.log` prints either `NaN` or just a repetition of the number :

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var qt_articles = new Array();
var tab_prix = new Array();

function print_nb_article(article, nb){
    $('#top_ten_nb_'+article).text(nb);
    var prix = $('#top_ten_nb_'+article+'_prix').val();
    var prix_tt =  $('.prix_'+article).text(prix*nb);


    if (prix_tt > 0) tab_prix.push(prix_tt);
    for(i=0; i<tab_prix.length; i++){
        prix_global += parseFloat(tab_prix[i]);
        console.log(prix_global);
    }
}

$('#plus_veste').click(function() {
    veste++;
    print_nb_article('veste', veste);
    return false;
});
```

My HTML:

```
<span id="prix_global">0</span>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: he's not console.printing veste lads - console.log(prix_global); .. prix global is the NAN problem.

Comment: and how i can define number and not object please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues, highlighted with comments:

```
var qt_articles = new Array();
var tab_prix = new Array();

function print_nb_article(article, nb) {
    $('#top_ten_nb_' + article).text(nb);
    var prix = $('#top_ten_nb_' + article + '_prix').val();
    // Note 1: Below, `prix_tt` will be a jQuery object, not a string or number.
    // You might want to set `prix_tt`, *then* set it as the text of the element.
    var prix_tt = $('.prix_' + article).text(prix * nb);

    // Note 2: So this comparison will compare `"[object Object]"` to `"0"`,
    // and get `false`. This'll get fixed if you fix the above.
    if (prix_tt > 0) tab_prix.push(prix_tt);
    for (i = 0; i < tab_prix.length; i++) {
        // Note 3: If the push *had* happened, here you'd be retrieving
        // the object and trying to parse `"[object Object]"` as a number.
        // This would also get fixed by the above.
        // Note 4: You're not setting `prix_global` to `0` before the loop,
        // so either it's `undefined` or you're going to get the wrong total
        prix_global += parseFloat(tab_prix[i]);
        console.log(prix_global);
    }

    // Note 5: Do you ever do anything with `prix_global`??
}

$('#plus_veste').click(function () {
    veste++;
    print_nb_article('veste', veste);
    return false;
});
```

Also note that your'e not declaring `i` anywhere (the variable you use for your loop), so you're almost certainly falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). That also applies to `veste` unless it's declared somewhere you haven't shown (and possibly others).

So to fix it:

1. Probably change the code under Note 1 to:

   ```
   var prix_tt = prix * nb;
   $('.prix_' + article).text(prix_tt);
   ```
2. Declare your variables in the innermost scope where you need them.
3. Set `prix_global` to `0` prior to the loop.
4. Do something with `prix_global` when you're done calculating it.

Other things I would do:

- Get rid of the globals. You almost certainly don't need them.
- Use `[]`, not `new Array()`, to create arrays.

Comment: can you send me correction please ?

Comment: @AlexMoody: I've added several pointers, but I think it's best if *you* rewrite the code, so you understand how it works.

Comment: thanks a lot yes it's my job but i have just a problem for find how declare number variable and not abject !!! thanks a lot !!

Comment: @AlexMoody: You don't declare variables with types in JavaScript. You just declare the variable (`var variableName`). The *values* you assign to variables have type, but the variables don't.

Answer (score 4):

Because you don't initialize `prix_global`. Add

```
var prix_global = 0;
```

In some browsers, it would be initialized to the element due to the id (but never to the parsed content of the span...). If you try to add to the initial value of the span, do

```
var prix_global = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prix_global').innerHTML);
... computations... 
document.getElementById('prix_global').innerHTML = prix_global;
```

More generally, pay attention to the initialization of your variables (see also `veste`) and their parsing (you're lucky with `prix*nb`).

Comment: That's **one** part of the problem (probably).